# Get duplicate rows and count based on multiple column

Tags: sql

I need to get the distinct rows based on a multiple column (area code,branch code and ID in this case) where there are duplicates of that column value. Along with other information from the row and the number of duplicate rows there are. for example:

```
ID     Areacode     Branch
--------------------------
1       100          200
1       101          200
2       102          201
2       102          201
3       103          200
```

I need this query to return

```
ID     Areacode     Branch   Count
--------------------------------
1       100          200      1
1       101          200      1
2       102          201      2
2       102          201      2
3       103          200      1
```

I tried

```
SELECT   Customer_ID,Areacode,Branch COUNT(*) as CNT
 FROM    Table1
 GROUP BY Customer_ID,Areacode,Branch
```

this resulted as

```
ID     Areacode     Branch   Count
--------------------------------
1       100          200      1
1       101          200      1
2       102          201      1
2       102          201      1
3       103          200      1
```

Comment: In your result, since you are grouping by `Customer_ID,Areacode,Branch`, count for `ID=2` should be 2 and must have unique row for `ID=2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    Customer_ID, Areacode, Branch,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_ID, Areacode, Branch) Count
FROM Table1;
```

I see two problems with your original query.  One is that you are grouping by the `Customer_ID` instead of the `ID`.  The other is that if you aggregate then you will not retain all the rows in the original table.  Using `COUNT` with a partition avoids this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Customer_ID, Areacode, Branch, COUNT(Areacode) as COUNT
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY Areacode
```

Please modify your query like this I guess this will definitely help you...

Comment: this is ok if am only counting based on area name.but i need to count based on branch also

Comment: This is invalid SQL to begin with and grouping by the same column that is used in the `count()` makes even less sense.